# GLSL Шейдер содержит неточности на мобильном устойстве

Tags: android, opengl, glsl, opengles, шейдеры

На десктопе шейдер рендерит кольцо правильно и четко:[image: Рендер на десктопе]

Но на мобильном андроид устройстве в кольце появляются неточности в сглаживании краев:[image: Рендер на андроиде]

Фрагмент шейдер:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision highp float;
#endif

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_circlePosition;
varying float v_radius;
varying float v_border;
varying float v_angleStart;
varying float v_angleEnd;
varying vec2 v_angleStartPos;
varying vec2 v_angleEndPos;

const vec4 backgroundColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

void main() {
    float dx = gl_FragCoord.x - v_circlePosition.x;
    float dy = gl_FragCoord.y - v_circlePosition.y;
    float a = mod(450.0 - degrees(atan(dy, dx)), 360.0);
    if (v_angleStart <= v_angleEnd ? a >= v_angleStart && a <= v_angleEnd : a >= v_angleStart || a <= v_angleEnd) {
        float dxs = gl_FragCoord.x - v_angleStartPos.x;
        float dys = gl_FragCoord.y - v_angleStartPos.y;
        float dxe = gl_FragCoord.x - v_angleEndPos.x;
        float dye = gl_FragCoord.y - v_angleEndPos.y;
        gl_FragColor = mix(backgroundColor, v_color,
            smoothstep(v_border, 0.0, min(sqrt(dxs * dxs + dys * dys), sqrt(dxe * dxe + dye * dye))));
    } else {
        float d = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        gl_FragColor = mix(v_color, backgroundColor,
            1.0 + smoothstep(v_radius, v_radius + v_border, d) - smoothstep(v_radius - v_border, v_radius, d));
    }
}
```

Comment: может precision highp float; во фрагментном шейдере устройство не поддерживает ? бывает такое. попробуй на другом.

Comment: @EvgenyKaravashkin, да ставил и mediump, все равно... что уже только не пробовал... сама странность в том, что на компьютере все просто отлично. И еще заметил, что на андроиде это как-то странно повторяется - через каждые 90 градусов, чем ближе к одной из четырех сторон - тем хуже работает сглаживание, буд-то сдвигаются точки, в которых рисуются круги, которыми сглаживаются края. Может есть какой-нибудь другой способ реализовать то, что я хочу?

Comment: Хм, я лично не вижу разницы между двумя картинками. Может быть под лупой выложите в чём разница.

Comment: PS. Для рассчёта расстояние грамотнее использовать функцию distance, И не до конца понял почуму в вас varying, а не uniform параметры.